# My program is stuck at readLine and never continues (Java Socket Programming)

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, readline, serversocket

I need to create a group of web servers(connected like a list) and each one of them have a list that has every server in it(port,id). When I try to send the list from a server to another, readLine() just gets stuck and never continues. The only time it continues, is when I stop(Ctrl + C) the server that sends the list. I add \n at the end of the output everytime and tried some stuff that I have read online but nothing works.

The bold code is where it gets stuck, I've tested it with System.out.println but it prints nothing, so it gets trapped in the condition I assume.

```
public class WebServer {
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int PORT = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int connect_port = 0;

        String info = args[0] + " " + args[1];
        //String info2 = "4356" + " " + "2";
        while(true) {
            if (id == 1) {
                servers.add(info);
            // servers.add(info2);
                    try {
                        ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(4355);
                        Socket connection = listenSocket.accept();
                        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                        for (String i : servers) {  //Sends the server list to the 2nd server
                            System.out.println(i);
                            outToServer.writeBytes(i + '\n');
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                    }
            } else {
                // This is every other node, they must be given the list by their previous
                // server
                try {
                    if (args[2].equals("connect")) {
                        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4355);
                        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        String i = null;
                        **while((i = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(i);
                            servers.add(i);
                        }**
             
                        servers.add(info);
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            
            Thread perdiodic = new Thread(new Periodic(servers,info));
            perdiodic.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried numerous solutions from other stack overflow questions from other programmers that phased the same thing but nothing worked.

Comment: Main server accepts a connection and writes all the servers, all the other servers connect to the main server and iterate until there's something to read.  
The server never says to a client when the list is terminated, should you close the connection from the main server after it sent the entire list?

Comment: Well right now my code is not where I would want it to be, and I try to understand some stuff so I have made it more specific. There is no supposed to be a main server, they are all the same and they can communicate and  health check (ACK) their next node/server. Right now I'm trying to understand how to pass the list that it's needed for the servers to know exactly what is going on, but I'm really struggling. I add the newline at the end for the readLine() to know where to stop but it seems that it is waiting for more when there is none. Only closing the connection makes it end for now.

Comment: You are reading lines but obviously the peer isn't sending lines. Or else there is an `IOException` which you are swallowing whole.

Comment: The servers are stuck in a loop waiting for the next line, the server that is providing the list needs to tell the receiver that the list is complete, so that the receiver can then do other stuffs, closing the connection is one way to do it, another way is specifying different messages for when it is sending a new server host (a new line) and when the list is completed (some other token, like the string "-list ended-", so that the client when receiving the line can check if the token match, it knows it can do other stuffs and exit the loop of receiving servers)